# Modify Yellow Dotted Line in GIMP

Tags: gimp, pixel-art

How do I remove or resize the marching ants from around the apple? It appeared when I used the move tool to move the position of the apple. It is in its own layer. I need to modify the image/layer outside that boundary but I am not allowed. I have tried select none. According to the select menu there is nothing selected. I'm a Photoshop user, but I'm trying to learn GIMP in order to teach my programing students how to illustrate games in a software that does not cost an arm & a leg, and is available in Linux.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can change the layer boundaries size using the `Layer Boundary Size` option under the `Layer` menu. Thank you @johnpharrell for the right term to search by.

[You can read more about it here.](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-resize.html)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Image Windows -> Appearance and untick "show layer boundary". Then you have to restart Gimp to make the changes.

Source: https://www.maketecheasier.com/make-gimp-look-like-photoshop/

That link may be helpful to you also. All the best.

Comment: ... and then forget about that setting, and wonder why you can suddenly not draw on a part of you image. The yellow line marks the boundary of the active layer - layers have a fixed size in GIMP.

Comment: @Michael Schumacher - I wondered if that would happen, the question then is how do you resize that boundary.